# Eclipse Neon 2 tool tip texts are in white and barely readable in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse, gtk, tooltip, gnome, eclipse-neon

I did the fix given by kayahr in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity) long time ago and it worked fine. But now it is not working. As you can see in the attached image the texts in the tool tip are barely readable as the texts are in white colour [image] and I couldn't find any place for setting the tool tip text color in `Eclipse Peferences`.  I recently updated Ubuntu perhaps it may be the reason for this error.  I tried `gnome color chooser` too but it also does not have a option to change the tool tip text color. How to fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse neon uses GTK+3 by default so refer this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/70665/112794 [Editing `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file is not required].

You can get your current by executing

> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme